# Where can I find a list of reliable Bitcoin full nodes?

Tags: nodes, p2p

I already know about [this list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes)  but it does not seem to be reliable or even up-to-date. Is there any other place where I can find a better list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best place is https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/nodes/leaderboard/

Nodes are rank according to various parameters

Answer (score 2):

A list of reliable nodes is inherently a trusted list. Therefore a reasonably trustable place to get some node IPs would be by hitting [the DNS seeds hardcoded in the reference client](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/d9a4738c9d3d3c8c8a0ca4e7ee6ced721da15d53/src/chainparams.cpp#L116-L129).
The list is community-curated, contains multiple sources, and the seeds are themselves dynamically managed. This makes it more resistant to censorship than a single website link.

As of now, there are 9 hardcoded DNS seeds:

```
seed.bitcoin.sipa.be // Pieter Wuille
dnsseed.bluematt.me // Matt Corallo
dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org // Luke Dashjr
seed.bitcoinstats.com // Christian Decker
seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch // Jonas Schnelli
seed.btc.petertodd.org // Peter Todd
seed.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl // Sjors Provoost
dnsseed.emzy.de // Stephan Oeste
seed.bitcoin.wiz.biz; // Jason Maurice
```

An easy way to get a list of IPs from them is by using the `dig` utility:

```
$ dig -t A dnsseed.emzy.de

; <<>> DiG 9.16.8-Debian <<>> -t A dnsseed.emzy.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39289
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 26, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1472
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dnsseed.emzy.de.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   116.202.196.182
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   121.147.241.223
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   47.198.209.213
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   188.134.74.188
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   51.161.36.145
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   35.180.187.229
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   5.61.50.213
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   79.98.31.253
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   45.151.125.218
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   15.161.90.31
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   216.8.188.217
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   34.82.27.114
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   42.148.150.79
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   157.245.140.86
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   108.7.205.58
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   49.247.215.43
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   101.162.90.21
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   151.48.99.212
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   24.21.229.157
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   101.179.1.53
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   202.184.0.102
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   138.68.14.104
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   54.217.186.6
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   144.76.138.23
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   84.67.126.130
dnsseed.emzy.de.    3600    IN  A   87.9.136.5
```

As a last resort you can also find [a list of hardcoded IPs in the Bitcoin-Core project](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/seeds/nodes_main.txt), updated before each release (roughly every ~6 months).